# Executing Select Layer By Attribute in Python Add-in Toolbar (ArcMap)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select-by-attribute, python-addin, error-000358

I'm having trouble with the button class of my code:

```
class OKButton(object):
"""Implementation for ok.button (Button)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.checked = False
def onClick(self):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = mxd.activeDataFrame
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer,"NEW_SELECTION",valueS)
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

The toolbar allows the user to select a data frame, a layer within it, a field within that layer, and a value within that field. In the above code, "layer" and "valueS" are the global variables referring to the chosen layer and value within one of its fields, respectively. However, when I run the code this error is raised:

ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

I know I need to replace the where_clause with an SQL expression based on the value the user selects (currently the global variable "value"). How could I go about this?

Comment: You need to create a string to hold your sql expression. Look at the examples for [Select Layer By Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) and there are many examples on this forum. You have made no attempt at it yet